# How to retrieve the value of an element in an ArrayList if it is not null by using a for loop?

Tags: java, android

In my app there there is data scraper, which retrieves info about movies from `themoviedb.org` `api`, one item that I want to retrieve is the `logo_path` of the `production_companies` which is provided as `JSONArray` , but there is possibility that the `value` of `logo_path` could be `null` (example available below)

***My goal is to achieve the following:-***

for example the `JSONArray` provides 6 elements (6 production companies)

if the `value` of `logo_path` of the last element (index 5) of the list is `null` then I want to retrieve the value of the fist element (index 0) which is not `null`

And if the value of `logo_path` of the last element (index 5) of the list is **not** `null` then I want to retrieve the value of the last element (index 5)

And if the first is `null` and the last one is also `null` , then I want to retrieve the `value` of one in between that is not `null`

***Update***

**production_companies  example**

```
"production_companies":[
{"id":429,"logo_path":"/2Tc1P3Ac8M479naPp1kYT3izLS5.png","name":"DC Comics","origin_country":"US"},
{"id":923,"logo_path":"/5UQsZrfbfG2dYJbx8DxfoTr2Bvu.png","name":"Legendary Pictures","origin_country":"US"},
{"id":9996,"logo_path":"/3tvBqYsBhxWeHlu62SIJ1el93O7.png","name":"Syncopy","origin_country":"GB"},
{"id":118865,"logo_path":null,"name":"Isobel Griffiths","origin_country":"GB"},
{"id":9993,"logo_path":"/2Tc1P3Ac8M479naPp1kYT3izLS5.png","name":"DC Entertainment","origin_country":"US"},
{"id":174,"logo_path":"/IuAlhI9eVC9Z8UQWOIDdWRKSEJ.png","name":"Warner Bros. Pictures","origin_country":"US"}]
```

***My code***

```
try {
                JSONArray production_companies = jObject.getJSONArray("production_companies");
                for (int i = 0; i < production_companies.length(); i++) {
                    if (jObject.getString(name: "logo_path").equalsIgnoreCase(string: "null")) // when the "logo_path" is "null"
                        movie.setStudioUrl(baseUrl + MizLib.getStudioUrlSize (mContext) + MizLib.getStringFromJSONObject (production_companies.getJSONObject (i - i), "logo_path", "")); // set the the first production company

                    else if (!jObject.getString ("logo_path").equalsIgnoreCase ("null")) // when the "logo_path" is not "null"
                        movie.setStudioUrl(baseUrl + MizLib.getStudioUrlSize (mContext) + MizLib.getStringFromJSONObject (production_companies.getJSONObject (i+1), "logo_path", "")); // set the the first production company

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {}
```

**Data types provided by api**

```
production_companies array[object]

name             string

id               integer

logo_path        string or null

origin_country   string
```

Comment: Ok thanks  I added some more info , is there something else I should do?

Comment: @Simayy if my post is more clear now , please remove downvote

Comment: @MCEmperor , if my post is more clear now , please remove downvote

Comment: I have/had not downvoted your post.

Comment: @Simayy , please forgive me , my mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear from your question what the JSON actually looks like, is the logo_path value a string with value "null", or is the logo_path element actually null.  The following assumes the latter.

You wrote:
*"when the value of logo_path of the last production company in the list equals null I want to set the fist production company"* ... else *"I want to set the last production company"*

Please follow along with this code and the comments I've added:

```
// get the array
JSONArray production_companies = jObject.getJSONArray("production_companies");

// ensure array has at least one entry
if (production_companies.length() > 0)
{
  // get the last element of the array as JSONObject (offset is length of array - 1)
  JSONObject lastCompany = production_companies.getJSONObject(production_companies.length() - 1);

  // is the "logo_path" property of lastCompany null?
  if (lastCompany.getString(name:"logo_path").equals("null"))
  {
    // then get first company ... i.e. offset zero
    JSONObject firstCompany = production_companies.getJSONObject(0);

    // set the first production company
    movie.setStudioUrl(baseUrl + MizLib.getStudioUrlSize (mContext) +
      MizLib.getStringFromJSONObject (firstCompany, "logo_path", "")); 
  }
  else
  {
    // else logo_path is not null, so use lastCompany
    movie.setStudioUrl(baseUrl + MizLib.getStudioUrlSize (mContext) +
      MizLib.getStringFromJSONObject (lastCompany, "logo_path", "")); 
  }
}
```

Comment: the logo_path is either a string or null

Comment: the string is something like this "/IuAlhI9eVC9Z8UQWOIDdWRKSEJ.png"

Comment: "production_companies":[{"id":2537,"logo_path":null,"name":"Kennedy Miller Productions","origin_country":"AU"},{"id":174,"logo_path":"/IuAlhI9eVC9Z8UQWOIDdWRKSEJ.png","name":"Warner Bros. Pictures","origin_country":"US"},{"id":41624,"logo_path":"/wzKxIeQKlMP0y5CaAw25MD6EQmf.png","name":"RatPac Entertainment","origin_country":"US"},{"id":79,"logo_path":"/tpFpsqbleCzEE2p5EgvUq6ozfCA.png","name":"Village Roadshow Pictures","origin_country":"US"}]

Comment: including this sample JSON in your question would've been very helpful.  I believe I've accurately answered your question, at least as I understand it

Comment: I used your code and compiled but this movie example is still not getting the first company

Comment: "production_companies":[
{"id":33,"logo_path":"/8lvHyhjr8oUKOOy2dKXoALWKdp0.png","name":"Universal Pictures","origin_country":"US"},
{"id":121470,"logo_path":null,"name":"87North Productions","origin_country":"US"},
{"id":86647,"logo_path":null,"name":"Odenkirk Provissiero Entertainment","origin_country":"US"},
{"id":123230,"logo_path":null,"name":"Eighty Two Films","origin_country":"US"},
{"id":154091,"logo_path":null,"name":"Perfect World Pictures","origin_country":""}],

Comment: as you can see the last one is null , the first one is /8lvHyhjr8oUKOOy2dKXoALWKdp0.png

Comment: Now it is working as expected , I changed null to "null"

Comment: You are a life savor

Comment: I've edited my answer, please make sure to accept the answer.  I was unaware that `JSONObject.getString()` would return the string "null" when the value is an unquoted **null**

Comment: Thank you,  I accepted the your answer , but because my reputation is below 15 I cannot upvote

Comment: can I ask one more thing please

Comment: if the first company and the last  company are null , but in the middle it is not null , how can I get the next one that is not null?

Comment: my answer is a "teach them to fish" answer ... a simple loop to find the first production_companies array element with a non-null logo_path instead of hard-coded entry #0 should be trivial, and you'll learn from the process

Comment: I'm really trying , but I can't figure it out

Comment: {"id":68112,"logo_path":"null","name":"Studio 100 Media","origin_country":"DE"},
{"id":104638,"logo_path":null,"name":"Studio B Animation","origin_country":""},
{"id":20187,"logo_path":"/bYdzRm9r74bIWlSRKIWZeZyDBFD.png","name":"Flying Bark Productions","origin_country":"AU"},
{"id":45198,"logo_path":"/q9s9KGhSsFEnpTmLLwprytB3T3d.png","name":"Deutscher Filmförderfonds","origin_country":"DE"},
{"id":268,"logo_path":"null","name":"FilmFernsehFonds Bayern","origin_country":"DE"},
{"id":2026,"logo_path":"null","name":"FFA","origin_country":"DE"}],

Comment: this is an example

Answer (score 0):

```
if(jObject.getString("logo_path").equalsIgnoreCase("null"))
```

this line is checking if it is string literal "null"
if you want to check if getString("logo_path") returns null, then you need to change it to

```
if(jObject.getString("logo_path") == null)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer , yes I changed to that and it helped

Answer (score 0):

I am most certain that you can simply try to:
logo_path == null.
if it doesn't work you can always define the string to be "-1" when it does not conatain anything.
Hopefully I helped.